# How to show in the time domain that in the frequency domain, multiplication with rect function with larger bandwidth has no effect?

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution, sampling-theory

In the frequency domain, $G(f) H(f) = G(f)$ if $H$ is a brickwall filter with a higher bandwidth than $G$.

**I want to show this in the time domain.**

*My attempt:* The time domain representation would be

$$
\int g(\tau) \operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{t-\tau}{T}\right) d\tau = g(t) ,
$$

where the sinc is the ideal brickwall filter with bandwidth $1/(2T)$.

By definition, if $g$ is bandlimited to $1/(2 T_g)$, it can be expanded using the WKS interpolation formula, having the samples as coefficients:

$$
g(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} g(n T_g) \operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{t-n T_g}{T_g}\right)
= \sum_{n-\infty}^{\infty} g[n] \operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{t-n T_g}{T_g}\right)
$$

Plugging this into the original equation:

$$
\int \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} g(n T_g) \operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{\tau-n T_g}{T_g}\right) \operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{t-\tau}{T}\right) d\tau \\
= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} g(n T_g) \left[ \int \operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{\tau-n T_g}{T_g}\right) \operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{t-\tau}{T}\right) d\tau \right]
$$

From this, the term in bracket would need to be equivalent to $\operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{t-n T_g}{T_g}\right)$ but only if $T \leq T_g$!

I tried calculating this integral using sines and exponentials but the expressions just get messier. I don't see this working out.

Comment: I don't know what WKS interpolation is but don't you just want to show that a convolution of two brickwall filters is another brickwall filter? You don't need to talk about $g$ at all.

Comment: WKS = Whittaker Kotelnikov Shannon a.k.a. “Sampling Theorem”. You are right, that’s what I “just” want to show. But hot to execute this formally/algebraically? (Just as a note: the two sinc’s have different normalization and time shift). I do not see where  condition like “T<Tg” would suddenly simplify things.